# Do not disable submit button when editing a question/answer

Tags: feature-request, edits

Please do not disable the "Save Edits" button when editing something. Sometimes I notice another typo/mistake right after clicking the button and use either escape to keep the form open or - more important - I use the "back" button to return to the form.

However, the submit button is now disabled so I have to copy the whole text, reload the page, and paste it again.

IMO this feature is good when creating new things to prevent accidental duplicates, but for editing it has no advantages at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems unnecessary to me. First off, I know this sounds old-stodgy-teacher-ish, but you should be checking for mistakes before you click "Save Edits" in the first place.

That said, the system knows we're all human — all of us who pass the CAPTCHA, anyways — and provides a five-minute window for changes to submissions. That is, if you wait for the edit to process, and then click "edit" again, the window will already be populated with your most recent changes, **and** further changes you make will be considered part of the first edit, for five minutes. (I just did this to this post, and you'll notice that the timestamp doesn't show that any edit occurred.)